# Flyway custom migration

Tags: java, flyway

I have encountered a problem with flyway and I don't know how to resolve it.

I have template of sql database, which initiates all tables, and basic data. This sql have been migrated on few production servers, and when I want to make little changes to this template (add more data for example) - of course there is a checksum mismatch. So the idea is to not put checksum in this base template migration, like in Flyway's schema creation.

Should I create custom MigrationExecutor? If that's correct approach, could you provide basic example how to use that custom executor, and within that executor how to get information about current running migration? I couldn't find anything about creating custom callbacks, resolvers or executers except Flyways doc's which doesn't give me any idea how to get what I want.

Flyway's version is 4.0.3

Comment: It sounds like you're mis-using flyway. The whole point of flyway is to have fully repeatable migrations so that you know exactly which version each server is running. When you add more data, create a new migration and put the data there.

Comment: Well, to make it clear - I make changes only in my first migration script which initiates db. So for example in this script I create table and then insert some html content in it. Then after some time, I want to add some more html content to this script, and I don't expect these changes to migrate on already running production apps. I want them only in next db initiation, so only when every migration script will run. I understand what you say about mis-using Flyway - but I'm curious, if there is possibility to turn off validation / checksum only on one migration script.

Comment: Flyway has _repeatable_ migrations. So for your html, for example, you could just update the existing content to whatever new value you want.

Comment: But repeatable migration is made at the and of flyway's migration process. There will be a problem, because user can update / add this contents too by admin panel. And when I will add it by migration, and run it at the end, it will override these changes made by user.